# No me funciona el selector this en jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectores

```
**Aca lo que hago es seleccionar la caja**

var caja = $("#caja");
caja.mouseover(() => {
  **cuando quiero agregarle el evento a la caja utilizo el selector this pero no me lo toma**

    $(this).css("background", "red");
});
```

tal vez sea por una actualizacion de jquery pero no tengo mucha idea por que no funciona

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Otener ID automático de elemento generado dináicamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/362115/otener-id-autom%c3%a1tico-de-elemento-generado-din%c3%a1icamente)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var caja = $("#caja");

caja.mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css("background", "red");
});
```

```css
#caja{
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "caja"></div>
```

Las `arrow functions` tienen un potencial increible a la hora de acortar muchisimo nuestro codigo, sin embargo hay que tener en cuenta que hay una ligera diferencia entre usar una `funcion normal` y usar una `arrow function`.

**Se considera que las funciones normales no estan deprecated o descontinuadas por lo siguiente:**

Las funciones normales conservan su contexto, las `arrow functions` lo pierden.

Por este motivo el `this` al que te refieres no es el mismo al usar una `function` en vez de usar una `arrow function`.

Comment: ah buenisimo muchas gracias!!

Comment: De nada, recuerda que si te fue de ayuda mi respuesta puedes darla como aceptada dandole al chulo que se encuentra en mi pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funcionó de la siguiente forma:

```
 $(function(){

    var caja = $("#caja");
    caja.mouseover(() => {    
        caja.css({"background-color":"red"});
    });
});
```

Al usar una variable no puedes utilizar $(this).